# How can i put image to come first than the title?

Tags: posts, css, noindex

im editing my posts and when i create one, it comes:

### **TITLE**

### **IMG**

**CONTENT**

and i want it like this:

### **IMG**

### **TITLE**

**CONTENT**

------------------got it---------------------------

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php $pclass = ($wp_query->current_post === 1)  ? 'middle-post-class' : 'first-last-class' ; ?>
<div id="post-style" <?php post_class($pclass); ?> >

<h1 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

<?php the_content(); ?>

</div>
```

--------------------end----------------------------

is the any way i can do it?
thanks.

Comment: Edit the file `single.php`.

Comment: What **Theme** are you using? Please post relevant Theme template code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the *post content* to add an image *outside of the call to `the_content()`*.

If you want to look into [implementing **Post Thumbnails (i.e. Featured Images)** into your Theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails).

Full implementation is outside the scope of a simple question-and-answer; however, in the end, your markup will change from this:

```
<h1 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

<?php the_content(); ?>
```

...to something like this:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(); } ?>

<h1 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

<?php the_content(); ?>
```